# Getting the minimum and maximum values in a randomly generated array in java

Tags: java, arrays, random

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Java {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int arr[] =  new int[10];
        Random Rand = new Random();

        int max = 0;
        int min = arr[0];


        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int RandNum = Rand.nextInt(10);
            arr[i] = RandNum;

            if (i == 0) System.out.print("[");

            System.out.print(arr[i] + " "); 

            if (i == 9) System.out.println("]");


            if (RandNum>max) {
                max = RandNum;
            }

            if (i > 0) {
                if (RandNum < arr[0]) {
                    min = RandNum;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Minimum number: " + min);
        System.out.println("Maximum number: " + max);       
    } 
}
```

I could get the maximum value, but not the minimum.. please bear with me, I'm a beginner, I've tried comparing the min value with the first array value, but I'm not sure if the min value should be array[0] or just 0.

Comment: **if(RandNum<arr[0]) , use your index variable here arr[i]** , maybe this is where you can get to understand whether its a typo or you are blindly programming to find **min**. Plus you are going to need a little help on improving your variable declaration style in java. I know this sounds rude and ugly, but you need a book or tutorial or more attention at lecture instead of thinking it as a stackoverflow attention grabbing problem :) ( I didn't down vote you still :) )

Comment: @Andreas won't work, OP does `int min=arr[0];`. `min` will remain `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to make sure that the first number is treated as the minimum,to give it some initial value, like

```
if(i==0){ 
    System.out.print("["); 
    min = RandNum;
}
```

This could be avoided by initializing `min`, with `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Then, you need to compare with `min`, not `array[0]` like,

```
if(i>0){
    if(RandNum<min){
        min = RandNum;
    }
}
```

Also, for what its worth, you could also do

```
System.out.println("Minimum number: " + Arrays.stream(arr).min());
System.out.println("Maximum number: " + Arrays.stream(arr).max());
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set min, you set it to zero (it's the default value for the integers in an initialized array). As such, no number generated will ever be greater than it. Set min to something like:

```
min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

And then check each newly generated number with each pass instead of skipping it for the first iteration of the loop.

You're also not checking the newly generated number with min, but with the first number of the array. Use this:

```
if(RandNum < min) /*do stuff*/;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You always comparing to arr[0] instead of comparing to "min".
you should write:

```
if(RandNum<min)
{
    min = RandNum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Notes:**

1. Set `min` and `max` to first array position.
2. You don't need check if the current index of for loop is greater than 0, just check if `min` variable is greater than current random number. e.g `if (min > number) min = number;`
3. Using a more simple logic to print the vector.

Using your own code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class App {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int count = 10;
        int arr[] = new int[count];
        Random random = new Random();

        int max = arr[0];
        int min = arr[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int number = random.nextInt(20);
            arr[i] = number;

            if (i == 0) {
                System.out.print("Array: [ " + number + " ");
            } else if (i == count - 1) {
                System.out.println(number + " ]");
            } else {
                System.out.print(number + " ");
            }

            if (max < number) {
                max = number;
            }

            if (min > number) {
                min = number;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Minimum number: " + min);
        System.out.println("Maximum number: " + max);
    }
}
```

A more simple approach, using `Arrays.toString`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class App {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int count = 10;
        int array[] = new int[count];
        int min = array[0], max = array[0];
        final Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int number = random.nextInt(10);
            array[i] = number;

            if (min > number) {
                min = number;
            }

            if (max < number) {
                max = number;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Array: " + Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.println("Minimum number: " + min);
        System.out.println("Maximum number: " + max);
    }
}
```

Using Java Streams API (Java 8 or newer):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class App {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        final int[] array = new Random().ints(10).toArray();
        System.out.println("Arrays: " + Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.println("Minimum number: " + Arrays.stream(array).min());
        System.out.println("Maximum number: " + Arrays.stream(array).max());
    }
}
```

Comment: While you fixed it in your code, you didn't explicitly mention one of the OP's primary issues which was the `if (RandNum < arr[0])` check instead of `if (RandNum < min)`. You should probably make that clear. Good answer though +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int min=0; // Define with cero
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
   // Logic of min
    arr[i] = RandNum;
    if(i ==0) // JUST in the first time
        {
        min=arr[0]
        }
   if(RandNum<min) // This inside your for
        {
        min = RandNum;
   }
}
```

Comment: Well my logic is that min will be first cero. Then it will take the first random inside in the for only once. I made it fast. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] =  new int[10];
    Random Rand = new Random();


    int max=0;
    int min=11;


    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        int RandNum = Rand.nextInt(10);
        arr[i] = RandNum;


        if(i==0) { System.out.print("["); } 

        System.out.print(arr[i] + " "); 

        if(i==9) { System.out.println("]"); }


        if(RandNum>max)
        {
            max = RandNum;
        }



            if(RandNum<min)
            {
                min = RandNum;
            }


    }

    System.out.println("Minimum number: " + min);
    System.out.println("Maximum number: " + max);   

    }
```

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you explained what the OP did wrong, clearly indicated what you changed, and explained why you did what you did and how it corrects the problem.